# Install Xorg on Arch-Linux-ARM

Tags: archlinux, gui, xorg, desktop

**H!@all**
I installed [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/) on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) every thing is working fine.
Now i want to install a graphical user interface (GUI, Desktop environment).
The [Arch-Linux-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) says nothing about how to install a GUI on a Raspbeery Pi. It should be the same as the installation on a PC, but it isn't. Even after the first steps in following the [installation instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg), I could not find the video driver.

```
lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D
```

My question is how do I install Xorg, sddm and KDE Plasma on the Raspberry Pi 4?
Do I need anything else to get the desktop environment working?

---

EDIT

**pacman -S xorg** gives me 50 options, which one should I choose?

```
1) xf86-video-vesa  2) xorg-bdftopcf  3) xorg-docs  4) xorg-font-util  5)
xorg-fonts-100dpi  6) xorg-fonts-75dpi  7) xorg-fonts-encodings 8) xorg-iceauth  9) xorg-luit  10)
xorg-mkfontdir  11) xorg-mkfontscale  12) xorg-server  13) xorg-server-common  14) xorg-server-devel 15)
xorg-server-xephyr  16) xorg-server-xnest  17) xorg-server-xvfb  18) xorg-server-xwayland  19) xorg-sessreg  20)
xorg-setxkbmap 21) xorg-smproxy  22) xorg-x11perf  23) xorg-xauth  24) xorg-xbacklight  25)
xorg-xcmsdb  26) xorg-xcursorgen  27) xorg-xdpyinfo 28) xorg-xdriinfo  29) xorg-xev  30)
xorg-xgamma  31) xorg-xhost  32) xorg-xinput  33) xorg-xkbcomp  34) xorg-xkbevd  35)
xorg-xkbutils 36) xorg-xkill  37) xorg-xlsatoms  38) xorg-xlsclients  39) xorg-xmodmap  40)
xorg-xpr  41) xorg-xprop  42) xorg-xrandr  43) xorg-xrdb 44) xorg-xrefresh  45)
xorg-xset  46) xorg-xsetroot  47) xorg-xvinfo  48) xorg-xwd  49) xorg-xwininfo  50) xorg-xwud
```

Comment: Last I checked (which was not recently) the Xorg driver used on Raspbian is just the framebuffer one (`fbdev`).

Comment: pacman -S xorg gives me 50 options, which one should I choose?

Comment: `pacman -S xorg | grep fbdev` Looks like it is not there though. The arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg mentions `xf86-video-fbdev` explicitly though.  Possibly it is just built into a base package...

Comment: No **fbdev**. I have expanded the post above with the pacman options, no fbdev included.

Comment: Okay, i have it: **pacman -S xf86-video-fbdev**. What next?

Comment: One more question. For the installation of SDDM and Plasma-Desktop **pacman** gives me this options: **1) libglvnd 2) imx-gpu-viv-dfb  3) imx-gpu-viv-fb  4) imx-gpu-viv-wl  5) imx-gpu-viv-x11** which one to chose, **imx-gpu-viv-x11** ?

Comment: If you have found the solution, so please create an answer and mark it as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work. For a one more question please create a new Question.